# Convert from C-CDA to FHIR using Azure convert-data api

Tags: azure, hl7-fhir, c-cda

I am using Microsoft `convert-data` API to convert data from one format to other. Not sure how I can pass an XML object within a JSON string as mentioned below :

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/healthcare-apis/azure-api-for-fhir/convert-data

The example from the above link states that we can include the data within the `inputData` parameter as a `valueString`. How can I send the XML data within JSON?

```
{
    "resourceType": "Parameters",
    "parameter": [
        {
            "name": "inputData",
            "valueString": "MSH|^~\\&|SIMHOSP|SFAC|RAPP|RFAC|20200508131015||ADT^A01|517|T|2.3|||AL||44|ASCII\nEVN|A01|20200508131015|||C005^Whittingham^Sylvia^^^Dr^^^DRNBR^PRSNL^^^ORGDR|\nPID|1|3735064194^^^SIMULATOR MRN^MRN|3735064194^^^SIMULATOR MRN^MRN~2021051528^^^NHSNBR^NHSNMBR||Kinmonth^Joanna^Chelsea^^Ms^^CURRENT||19870624000000|F|||89 Transaction House^Handmaiden Street^Wembley^^FV75 4GJ^GBR^HOME||020 3614 5541^HOME|||||||||C^White - Other^^^||||||||\nPD1|||FAMILY PRACTICE^^12345|\nPV1|1|I|OtherWard^MainRoom^Bed 183^Simulated Hospital^^BED^Main Building^4|28b|||C005^Whittingham^Sylvia^^^Dr^^^DRNBR^PRSNL^^^ORGDR|||CAR|||||||||16094728916771313876^^^^visitid||||||||||||||||||||||ARRIVED|||20200508131015||"
        },
        {
            "name": "inputDataType",
            "valueString": "Hl7v2"
        },
        {
            "name": "templateCollectionReference",
            "valueString": "microsofthealth/fhirconverter:default"
        },
        {
            "name": "rootTemplate",
            "valueString": "ADT_A01"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you're looking to do? The question title says "SFU3 to FHIR" (I assume you mean STU3), but your body talks about converting from XML. The only XML input allowed by the API is C-CDA. If you are converting from STU3, that needs to be in JSON.

Comment: @Ashavan Sorry, I meant C-CDA, Can you help what should I use in that case? I have edited the title.

Comment: Then your inputDataType would be "Ccda", your inputData would be the C-CDA XML, and the templateCollectionReference would be "microsofthealth/ccdatemplates:default" if you're using a default template. rootTemplate will depend on exactly which C-CDA document you are converting.